# C++ Compiled Code Not Running on WebServer Using CGI

Tags: c++, webserver, cgi

I'm trying to compile and run my C++ code on a web server (GoDaddy) using CGI. I've compiled my code on my PC that runs Linux Debian distro. However, every time that I try to run my code using my Internet browser, I get "500 Internal Server Error".

After asking the web server customer service, I found out that the error log is the following:

```
[Tue Jan 20 09:47:59.939859 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 29555:tid 140270383359744] [client 152.3.43.176:64059] AH01215: out.cgi: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by out.cgi), referer: http://.com/tweet.html
[Tue Jan 20 09:47:59.939909 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 29555:tid 140270383359744] [client 152.3.43.176:64059] AH01215: out.cgi: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by out.cgi), referer: http://.com/tweet.html
```

How should I compile my code to not get these errors?

Comment: Install libstdc++.so.6 on your server.

Comment: Find all the dependencies (libraries, headers) which does your application use and ship it with your application or use system internal tools to satisfy the dependencies.

Comment: Michael, I don't have full control over the webserver, it is a limited version hosting so that I cannot install anything on the server or ask the web server administrator to install it for me.

Comment: Victor, do you mean I just need to upload libstdc++.so.6 to the same folder as the CGI program?